# Trying to Create Menu in Wordpress

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu

I have been trying to create a mega menu on the WordPress website. The problem that I am facing is not able to create a mega drop-down for different services.

What I want to create is:

When should I hover on services (on the Navigation bar) a drop should show up & that dropdown menu shows 3 columns of different services & each column contains their related services.

I have attached the images file for your ready reference and a link from where I got these is
https://qxglobalgroup.com/

My aim is to create Navigation bar like the above link.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

[image]